# Need help understanding a definite integration solution

Tags: integration

The following solution is from a textbook. Can someone please tell me what's happening to the highlighted x^2 after the integration? Why are we discarding it?

[image: integration]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left ( \frac12 + x^2\right )^2-x^2 = \frac14 + x^2 + x^4 - x^2$$

Comment: The simple (a + b)^2 formula, only I could miss such a thing :( Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The expansion of `[1/2 + x^2]` is `1/4 + x^4 + 2*(1/2)*x^2` (by `(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab`). This `2*(1/2)*x^2` reduces to `x^2` and cancels with the `-x^2` highlighted in the question.

Comment: I think this is very well demonstrated in Ron Gordon's post, who posted 8 minutes before you. So why the duplicate answer?

Comment: Someone already answered, but thanks mate :)

Comment: Sorry, I did mine before the other answer, but it took some time to get posted :p